# git clone how to fake user agent

Tags: git

I would like to fake the user-agent during a `git clone`. I am behind a proxy that requires user/password and a specific user-agent. I already did it for `wget` and not yet for `git clone`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Use `ssh://` instead of `https://`. That's likely to not be blocked by your proxy.

Comment: Well, everything is blocked apart from `80`, `8080` and `443` ...

Comment: Tell your employer that you cannot work under these conditions.

Comment: Looks like a good time to look into the git sources to see for yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`http.useragent` config variable](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html).

Answer (score 1):

Or set the environment variable:

> **`GIT_HTTP_USER_AGENT`** sets the user-agent string used by Git when communicating over HTTP. The default is a value like git/2.0.0.

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables