# Is there a way to configure what mercurial sends in the user-agent header?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, user-agent

With git, you can [configure the `http.useragent` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117355/git-clone-how-to-fake-user-agent), but I'm not aware of a similar setting in mercurial. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: afaik the answer is 'no'. It's set to the used mercurial version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct support for it, but it should be possible to enable it with an extension:

```
from mercurial import url, extensions

def wrap_opener(orig, ui, authinfo=None):
  result = orig(ui, authinfo)
  agent = ui.config("http", "useragent")
  if agent:
    ah = result.addheaders
    for i in xrange(len(ah)):
      if ah[i][0] == "User-agent":
        ah[i] = ("User-agent", agent)
  return result

def uisetup(ui):
  extensions.wrapfunction(url, "opener", wrap_opener)
```

This allows you to set the user agent in your `~/.hgrc` or `.hg/hrc` with:

```
[http]
useragent = "..."
```

Caveat: I only tested that the extension does not break Mercurial and the opener object is modified appropriately, I did not actually verify that the proper User-agent header is being sent across the network.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for writing it. The user-agent header was set as specified.